# Unable to start Rserve from java in linux environment

Tags: java, linux, exec, rserve

This small code try to start Rserve from JAVA:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
                boolean debug = false;
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("R CMD Rserve");
                p.waitFor();
        }
}
```

This starts Rserve process successfully on windows. However in linux environment, it fails to start Rserve even though there is no exception thrown.

I am able to start Rserve from command line in linux using command: `R CMD Rserve` . So, R and Rserve installation is not an issue here.

How can I start Rserve from JAVA in linux environment?

Answer (score 0):

In a Linux environment, the shell processes the command you are issuing.  As such, Java needs to call the shell executable and tell it to execute the `R` command and its parameters.  Try changing `"R CMD Rserve"` to the following (replace `/bin/bash` with the path to your preferred Linux shell):

`"/bin/bash -c 'R CMD Rserve'"`

If that doesn't work,  try also specifying the full path to the `R` executable in the single quotes.

Comment: Still no success! Returns exit status 1.

Comment: Change `'R CMD Rserve'` in the above to include the full path to the R executable.  For example (replace with the actual path of your install): `"/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/R CMD Rserve'"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("R CMD Rserve --vanilla");
```

for linux environments.